# how to set value for max-beans-in-cache in weblogic-ejb-jar.xml

Tags: ejb, weblogic, osb

I need to understand what all factors to consider in order to set up max-beans-in-cache parameter for my ejb. Can someone help me please?

My scenario:

OSB having single cluster of 4 servers, each server running 3 services each.

My app server is a group of 4 clusters , where each cluster is having 2 managed servers. My ejb is deployed on the cluster.

Comment: You are using stateful or entity bean with OSB ?

Comment: Hi, I am using stateful bean.